# HttpClient 403 Catching Expired API Token .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#

The API Swagger endpoint I am working with requires I create a HttpClient with the Bearer token attached.

I do it like this:

```
public static HttpClient BuildClient(string baseUrl, string username, string password)
    {
        AuthenticationClient client = new AuthenticationClient(new HttpClient())
        {
            BaseUrl = baseUrl
        };

        CreateTokenRequest tokenRequest = new CreateTokenRequest
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password
        };

        CreateTokenResponse createTokenResponse = client.CreateAsync(tokenRequest).Result;

        HttpClient httpClient;
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", createTokenResponse.Access_token);

        return httpClient;
    }
```

Some of my code runs longer than the life of the Bearer token.

Is it possible to catch a 403 Forbidden, the token expiring, and refresh it at this level?

I suspect, although could be completely wrong, that i should implement something in a custom HttpMessageHandler but cannot work out how to do it.

```
public class MyHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{

}
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Here is my solution.

The one issue I have seen that haven't worked out how to fix is that if I multi-thread calls to the API it calls for a new token for each thread.

Please let me know if you see any problems with it?

Usings:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Cloud.API.CloudService;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Code:

```
public class SCHelpers
{
    private static readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

    public static HttpClient BuildClient(string baseUrl, string username, string password)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient;
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClient = new HttpClient(new RetryMessageHandler(handler, baseUrl, username, password)) { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return httpClient;
    }

    private static string GetToken(string baseUrl, string username, string password)
    {
        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue("Token", out string _))
        {
            AuthenticationClient client = new AuthenticationClient(new HttpClient())
            {
                BaseUrl = baseUrl
            };

            CreateTokenRequest tokenRequest = new CreateTokenRequest
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password
            };

            CreateTokenResponse tokenResponse = client.CreateAsync(tokenRequest).Result;

            MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
            {
                AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
                //cacheEntryOptions.AbsoluteExpiration = tokenResponse.Expires;
                SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
            };

            _memoryCache.Set("Token", tokenResponse.Access_token, cacheEntryOptions);
        }

        string token = _memoryCache.Get<string>("Token");
        return token;
    }

    public class RetryMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly string _baseUrl;
        private readonly string _password;
        private readonly string _username;
        public RetryMessageHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerhandler, string baseUrl, string username, string password) : base(innerhandler)
        {
            _baseUrl = baseUrl;
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string token = GetToken(_baseUrl, _username, _password);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle 403 exception in the browser.

Simply make another authentication call to the OpenID server, same as the initial authentication request. If you're still logged in on the SSO server, it will just return response with new `access_token`.